# How to wait for the last cmd command to generate a file, and then read the binary of this file, using Rust

Tags: windows, rust, cmd, lua

I am writing a program, the desired effect is to generate a lua file, then compile this lua on windows platform using luac.exe and read the binary value of the generated luac.out file.

My code is here

```
fn test(lua_path: PathBuf, luac_path: String) -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let index = luac_path.rfind("/").ok_or("path fail")?;
    let (path, file) = luac_path.split_at(index + 1);
    let cmd_str = format!("/c cd /d {} && .\\{} {}", path, file, lua_path.display());
    let child = Command::new("cmd").raw_arg(cmd_str).spawn()?;
    let output = child.wait_with_output()?;
    if !output.status.success() {
        let output_str = String::from_utf8(output.stderr)?;
        return Err(output_str.into());
    }

    // Without the following code, luac.out will be generated normally.
    // But once the following code is added, luac.out will be generated as 0kb and receive an access denied error
    let out_path = Path::new(&path).join("luac.out");
    let mut out_file = File::create(&out_path)?;
    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    out_file.read_to_end(&mut buf)?;
    let result = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf).to_string();
    Ok(result)
}
```

My guess is that after executing child.wait, the file is not created to completion and then the program accesses it causing an error, how do I fix this?

Comment: You should read the documentation for [`File::create`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.create): *"This function will create a file if it does not exist, and __will truncate it__ if it does."* You probably want [`File::open`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.open) instead.

Comment: I'd also suggest `Command::current_dir()` instead of running `cd` as part of the command.